# Was Cadet Jones playing any particular video game?

Tags: sound-effects, police-academy

Watching `Police Academy` and just thoroughly amazed as one should be by Michael Winslow's performance as Cadet Larvell Jones.

Their first night in the academy, he is in his room making like he is playing a video game. I'm not all up on my early 80's video games. Were the sound effects he was making supposed to be any specific video game, or just an amalgamation of the typical sounds from the games of that era?

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about this scene (starting at 1:19), then there isn't a specific game he's playing. In the middle of the sequence, you hear a specific sequence which sounds a lot like Donkey-Kong (I believe) or some other Mario variant. The other noises are random blaster noises. Plus the "ass-hole" comment was definitely not from a video game, lol.

I believe this is just Michael Winslow doing noises which were discernible as video game noises. Something which he does very well.

Comment: Yup, that is the bit I'm talking about. Yeah... "ass-hole" DEFINITELY wouldn't have been in video games back then! LOL . I can't believe Wilson's talent - case in point, I give you this: [Michael Wilson performing Led Zeppelin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HHMA1Dpo5M). BLOWS MY MIND!

Comment: Err, **Winslow**. Can't believe I misspelled it - TWICE - in that comment. :/